# Is NumPy's array system different from PIL's Image.fromarray()?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, mandelbug

This is related to a bigger mandelbug, but this is a major part of it.

If I do this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
   
l = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
l[0,0,:] = 1
img = Image.fromarray(l, "RGB")
img.save("ex.png")
```

I get this:

[image: Wrong Pixels.]

This is clearly not the operation I performed on the image. If you look at the top left, it shows a bunch of pixels made Green, Blue and Red etc. whereas I would expect it to make 1 pixel (the top left) white/grey.

What is happening?

Comment: Try a different value then "1" , since "1" does not really change anything. You should use sth like 255 to see a difference

Comment: `1` on `uint8` scale would be almost black, don't you think?

Comment: I used your code (and added np.uint8 at the array init) and used a higher number than 1 , the snippet seems to work. What kind of IDE / environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit stupid - thinking in terms of `np.float64`, yet using `np.uint64`.

The answer was simply to use a number a bigger than 1.

(I also fixed some Library-build errors that led to the colouring of multiple pixels.)

Sorry for posting the question!